# Does ScrollView tag in android 2.1 widget work?

Tags: android

I am developing an application using android 2.1. creating a widget for it, I have created a simple widget having text view layout, big font. I want to add the scrollable view so if text goes out of boxes, user can scroll. But whenever I add  tag. Widget doesn't work, any solution?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:layout_margin="5sp"
    >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            >

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
                android:text="slkjflasjdlkfjaslkjflksjf  saldjfslkjdflksf lskjdflkasjdlkfjsa lkfklsa dfsakldjfksajdfkljasdklfjlaksdfkla sdlf askj fljsalfk aslkjfklsdjf lksadkfjsadkljf lksadjkf sadlkjfksa jfkljs dklfj skldjf klsadjkflsa dklfj sadkl fklsadj fklasdj kfjsa dklfjsadkljfklasdjklfsjadfjklsadj;as;fdjaljfd;klajd;klfaklsdjfkas fljldfjasdfjiojsdkljfiowejfisdklfkldjf k kljsedjr ilejicjdisfkeriejfcsdijioerfid cvisdjis kl jiowejfliwejlwjfkjdlkfjsjr i  sijflessdf;lejfdejcjwejfij nlkefi ewijtioejifeiofrjiowejflie vilejeijioejfeojvolijsljfoisdjie ff iejieifiejfswjiflisijiejeifjeilfjelis fs ijfis efjsijfilesjflsjlfe sif j"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                />

        </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "widget doesn't work"?

Comment: Gives "Problem Loading Widget"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)

> Creating the App Widget layout is simple if you're familiar with
>   Layouts. However, you must be aware that App Widget layouts are based
>   on RemoteViews, which do not support every kind of layout or view
>   widget.
>
> A RemoteViews object (and, consequently, an App Widget) can support
>   the following layout classes:
>
> ```
> FrameLayout
> LinearLayout
> RelativeLayout
> GridLayout
> ```
>
> And the following widget classes:
>
> ```
> AnalogClock
> Button
> Chronometer
> ImageButton
> ImageView
> ProgressBar
> TextView
> ViewFlipper
> ListView
> GridView
> StackView
> AdapterViewFlipper
> ```
>
> **Descendants of these classes are not supported.**
>
> RemoteViews also supports ViewStub, which is an invisible, zero-sized View you can use to lazily inflate layout resources at runtime.

So no, **ScrollView is not supported in Widgets.**

Comment: ScrollView is a subclass of FrameLayout, see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Comment: @Malfist As I wrote: `Descendants of these classes are not supported.`

Comment: @AmolKamble None that I know of. The best solution is to avoid using ScrollView in a Widget. Widget are not built to support them.

Comment: @AmolKamble: "is there a workaround?" -- on Android 3.0+, you can create app widgets that scroll, using `ListView` or `GridView`, but that is it.

Comment: @AmolKamble, sorry, missed that part.